# Get boolean from UFT Checkpoint without throwing error if check fails

Tags: hp-uft

I'm using this kind of boolean in my code:

```
Dim found
found = FileContent("TestFile.docx").Check CheckPoint("TestFile.docx")

If(found) Then
    'Do stuff
End If
```

The problem is I don't want it to throw an error if the check fails.

What shall I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Most of the point of a checkpoint is to report a pass/fail state into the test results, so if you just want to check that the file exists, use a `filesystemobject` instead.

Answer (score 0):

filesystemobject would most likely be your best bet.  You can do a .Exist

Comment: Hello, can you give me an example please? I need to check that a file exists with a specific content

Comment: Wrap it in an IF statement then.  So "Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"), Is FS.FileExists("C:\TestFile.docx") Then ..." do what you need to do.  You can also open the text file and read a line, using something like InStr to check to see if certain text is in the file.  So "Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\TestFile.docx"), strLine = objFile.ReadLine, If InStr(strLine, "text to search for") Then ..." do what you need to do